# Oil in coolent on my volkswagen Touareg

Tags: coolant

The coolant light came on so I took it to a mechanic he flushed it and put knew coolant some special g-12 coolant but the light came on again so I took a look at it and found oil in it . So I looked at the oil stick and the oil has no sign water I don't understand why the coolant would have oil. But the oil has no sign of water.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be *sure* what the substance is, in your coolant.

How are you determining that it is oil and not transmission fluid? They often get confused by people.

A good way to be sure is to check the levels of the transmission fluid and oil, depending on the leakage, usually the low level one is leaking.

If you are absolutely sure it is indeed engine oil, then it would most likely not be your transmission cooler (which would be one of my first guesses for something in the coolant). If it were the transmission cooler you'd see trans fluid.

It most likely wouldn't be a head gasket unless you see coolant when checking the oil.

I would guess an intake gasket, sight unseen.

Answer (score 0):

Check if its not residue (brown stuff) coming from your overflow reseviour, otherwise I'd say it could possibly be a rear main seal (have to remove transmission to replace) or head gasket (which I highly doubt unless you've overheated it around the red marker for a long period of time).

Comment: We have never overheated it, but it is oil in the coolant. Ive stuck my finger in the actual container and oil was on my finger.

Comment: Okay, there a multiple things that can cause this which are 1. Transmission cooler
2. Head gasket
3. Inlet manifold
4. Pellets 
I reckon it could be the transmission cooler, but there is no way to tell for sure. Your going to have to goto a garage regardless. And do not drive with it like this as it will block up your cooling system. You can drive to a mechanic etc but not long distances.